# How to Capture user inputted text using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, enter

I have the following input element on the page:

```
Search: <input id="example" />
```

I would like to capture the information the user enters in this box, when the user hits enter and display it on screen:

```
  $(window).keypress(function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 13) {
          $("input[name=example]").val().insertAfter('#example');
      }
```

The following results in an undefined:

```
$("input[name=example]").val() is undefined
```

How do you capture user inputed text?

Comment: `id != name`. ;) $("input#example").val() should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a `name`.

Use the `#` selector: `$('#example')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#example").val().insertAfter('#example');       
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you is using `id` and not `name`, do:

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $("input#example").val().insertAfter('#example');
    }
});
```